# How to use key and value in a `borg create` command using for loop(or not)

Tags: bash, key-value, bash4

I have some sites on a server and I want to only backup their webroots creating a new repository for each site. With bash 4 I can use a dictionary.

```
declare -A sites=(["site1"]="/var/www/webroot1"
                  ["site2"]="/var/www/webroot2"
                  ["site3"]="/var/www/webroot3"
                  )
```

The borg command is:

```
borg create  --verbose  --progress --list --stats  --show-rc  --compression lz4 $REPOSITORY::{$key}-{now:%Y-%m-%d} $value
```

How can I create a for loop that will use both key and value in this command?
Something like the following but instead doing `echo`, use the keys and values in the command and backup all sites one by one.

```
for i in "${!projects[@]}";
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${sites[$i]}"
done
```

I **don't** want to just echo the key and value. I want to use them in **one command**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```
declare -A sites=(["site1"]="/var/www/webroot1"
                  ["site2"]="/var/www/webroot2"
                  ["site3"]="/var/www/webroot3"
                  )

for key in "${!sites[@]}"; do
    borg create --verbose --progress --list --stats --show-rc --compression lz4 "$REPOSITORY"::{"$key"}-{now:%Y-%m-%d} "${sites[$key]}"
done
```

It assumes the variable `REPOSITORY` is also defined to some value.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i have understood your question well. In python you can write the following code

```
sites=[
    ("site1", "/var/www/webroot1"),
    ("site2", "/var/www/webroot2"),
    ("site3", "/var/www/webroot3")
]
##create a dictionary called arr{} with key: site and value:webroot
arr = {}
for k,v in sites:
    if k in arr:
        arr[k].append(v)
    else:
        arr[k] = v
print(arr)
```

The output will be:

```
{'site1': '/var/www/webroot1', 'site2': '/var/www/webroot2', 'site3': '/var/www/webroot3'}
```

You can now manipulate the dictionary `arr{}` above as you wish.

To execute the command `borg create --verbose --progress --list --stats --show-rc --compression lz4 $REPOSITORY::{$key}-{now:%Y-%m-%d} $value`then you need to loop through the dictionery `arr{}` like so:

```
for k,v in arr.items():
   borg create --verbose --progress --list --stats --show-rc --compression lz4 $REPOSITORY::{k}-{now:%Y-%m-%d} v
```

I have replaced `{site}` with `{k}` and `/var/www/webroot` with `v` in the `borg create command`.

Comment: I need to execute the command `borg create  --verbose  --progress --list --stats  --show-rc  --compression lz4 $REPOSITORY::{$key}-{now:%Y-%m-%d} $value`. I don't need to just print or echo the keys and values, I am trying to use them as variables. I need to do `borg create  --verbose  --progress --list --stats  --show-rc  --compression lz4 $REPOSITORY::{site}-{now:%Y-%m-%d} /var/www/webroot`
. How can this be done for all keys and values in the dictionary?